# Reading ints from file with C

Tags: c, file, io

This is a very simple question, but I can't seem to find something about it in here already. I want to read two integers from a file with C. My code now is this:

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int s[80];
    int t;

    if((fp=fopen("numbers", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    } else {
        fscanf(fp, "%d%d", s, &t);
        printf("%d %d\n", s[0], s[1]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I get the first integer from the file, but the next one is just a random number. My file is like this:

```
100 54
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d%d", s, &t);
```

is putting one of the ints in `s[0]` and the other in `t`, but you are printing out `s[0]` (which is your first int) and `s[1]`, which is uninitialized (and hence "random").

Answer (score 3):

You are reading the results into s and t but printing only s ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on this line:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d%d", s, &t);
printf("%d %d\n", s[0], s[1]);
```

You're reading into s[0] and t, but printing s[0] and s[1]. Either of the following would work as a replacement:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d%d", s, &t);
printf("%d %d\n", s[0], t);
```

Or:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &s[0], &s[1]);
printf("%d %d\n", s[0], s[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize it. You pass pointer to `s`, which means (here) the first element, as a first parameter. What do you expect to show up in `s[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing the fscanf, you are using one set of variables.
But when you do the printf, you are using another.

One way to get it working correctly:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  int s[80];

  if((fp=fopen("numbers", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
  } else {
    fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &s[0], &s[1]);
    printf("%d %d\n", s[0], s[1]);
    fclose(fp);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read into `&s[0]` and `&s[1]` **or** print out `s[0]` and `t`.